# Can't look at historical audits in suggested edits queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-audits

It used to be possible to look back at historical suggested edit review audits and be shown success/failure/"This item is not reviewable" (if you'd skipped it).

However, now attempting to look back at historical audits the review fails to load and you receive the following error toast:

> An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.

[Example audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29430323)

Browser console shows:

> POST https://stackoverflow.com/review/next-task/29430323
>
> 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Bug: The past is broken.

Comment: They probably fixed a bug somewhere else.. :D

Comment: just to link the two: also reported on MSE 2 days later: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367738/786798